# Cannot find google-cloud-sdk in python flask application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

First i got the following error

app-development is one of the file in my google cloud

```
****appconfig.py -A app-development update ./app.yaml****
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "appengine_config.py", line 4, in <module>
        from google.appengine.ext import vendor
    ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

Next i taught that google cloud is not installed i tried installing it is saying alredy installed i don't know why my file is failing

```
  sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
        Reading package lists... Done
        Building dependency tree       
        Reading state information... Done
        google-cloud-sdk is already the newest version (240.0.0-0).
        0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

next i tried by going to python terminal to test

```
>>> import google
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google
```

What i am missing i have also installed all the dependence of python

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python.
[sudo] password for mdvenkatesh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python is already the newest version (240.0.0-0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 version python 2.7 version
Moreover i am seeing the redme.txt file and following the

Moreover i  tried with `google init`

```
1)app-development
2) app-deployment
```

It is showing the following two projects which are in my google app engine

Answer (score 0):

The `google.appengine` package is specific to the App Engine Standard Python 2.7 runtime, and is not available elsewhere, including the Python 3.7 runtime.

You didn't include how you're attempting to run your application, but if you're trying to run it locally, you need to use the `dev_appserver.py` command. See more details here: "[Getting Started with Flask on App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env)"